# Setting time limits on axis removes all values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this simple data:

```
structure(list(ID = 1:2, timing = structure(c(1654641111.14, 
                                              1654640774.523), tzone = "CET", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                 -2L))

  ID                  timing
1  1 2022-06-08 00:31:51.140
2  2 2022-06-08 00:26:14.523
```

When I plot using `ggplot2`, I get this:

```
ggplot(df_test,
       aes(x = ID,
           y = timing)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image: Basic plot]

But when I set limits, the graph is empty:

```
lims <- as.POSIXct(strptime(c("35:00", "25:00"), 
                              format = "%M:%OS",
                              tz = "CET"))
  
  
ggplot(df_test,
       aes(x = ID,
           y = timing)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_datetime(limits = lims)

Warning message:
Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

I tried to find any solution, but I can't figure out why the limits remove all my values. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply due to your limits being round the wrong way (they should be earliest, latest whereas you have latest, earliest).

So you can do:

```r
ggplot(df_test,
       aes(x = ID,
           y = timing)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_datetime(limits = rev(lims))
```

[image]